# reloadData() isn't work in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reloaddata

So, I have trouble - can't reloadData of TableView, in command line I see good data - when I click button `idMeet` is changed, but in Simulator I don't see refresh table view after click on the button, and `idMeet` is changed and my query is changed too. I understand that I must use `tableView.reloadData()`, but don't understand where write it for correct working?

```
    var x = true;

        @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet var tbRouteData: UITableView!
        @IBAction func act(sender: UIButton) {
            x = !x
            getInfo()
        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
        }

        override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
            self.getTmp()
        }

        func getInfo() -> NSMutableArray {
            sharedInstance.database!.open()
         var idMeet: Int
         if x {
                idMeet = 1
            } else {
                idMeet = 2
            }

            print(idroute)

            let selectInfo: FMResultSet! = sharedInstance.database!.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM t1 AS one JOIN t2 AS two ON (one.id = two.id AND two.line_id = ?) ORDER BY two.position ASC", withArgumentsInArray: [idMeet])
    ...
            return tmp
        }

    func getTmp(){

        infoTmp = NSMutableArray()
        infoTmp = getInfo()
    }


    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return infoTmp.count
    }

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PrivateCell

        let my:Info = infoTmp.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! Info
        cell.listOfStop.text = my.Name.uppercaseString
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: there is no reload in your code

Comment: I asked where reload must be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

1. The `getTmp` function should reload the data:

   ```
   func getTmp(){
       infoTmp = getInfo()
       tbRouteData.reloadData()
   }
   ```
2. Now that you have a function that populates the property and reloads the table, `act` should call that, rather than `getInfo`:

   ```
   @IBAction func act(sender: UIButton) {
       x = !x
       getTmp()
   }
   ```

   When you call `getInfo`, that doesn't set `infoTmp`. And by calling `getTmp` that centralizes the population of `infoTmp` and reloading of the table in one place.
3. If you're not seeing any data in your table view, make sure that you've set the `delegate` of the table view accordingly. You can do that either in IB, or programmatically:

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       tbRouteData.delegate = self
   }
   ```

   This assumes, of course, that you defined your view controller to conform to `UITableViewDataSource` and have implemented the appropriate methods. Without seeing those methods, we can't tell if there might be some further issue there.

Answer (score 1):

```
func getTmp(){

        infoTmp = NSMutableArray()
        infoTmp = getInfo()
        tbRouteData.reloadData()
    }
```

**Write this code and this will reload your tableview with new data after the array fills up**

Comment: thank you, but it isn't working, tableView isn't reload. In Simulator I see info of when idMeet = 1, but idMeet = 2 (it see in command line)

Comment: do you EVER see data in the tableVIew?  Have you linked the data source and data delegate?  Are the tableView methods being called?

Comment: no, I don't see new data in the tableView. I see that "idMeet" is changed after click on the button, but data in tableView isn't change. Yes the data source and data delegate were linked.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when tableView data array become changed then tableView should reload. In this case at the end of the button action method reload tableview.

```
@IBAction func act(sender: UIButton) {
        x = !x
        getInfo()
        tbRouteData.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: isn't working, tableView isn't reload. In Simulator I see info of when idMeet = 1, but idMeet = 2 (it see in command line)

Answer (score 0):

The reload data should be completed within the button but after the getInfo() has been completed. The following should work:

```
    @IBAction func act(sender: UIButton) {
        x = !x
        getInfo()
        tbRouteData.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: thank you, but it isn't working, tableView isn't reload. In Simulator I see info of when idMeet = 1, but idMeet = 2 (it see in command line)

Comment: Are you able to print the new data to ensure that it is correctly populating? It is possible that it is refreshing correctly but the data hasn't changed

Comment: so, after click I get new data in command line from DB, I will search where my new data don't want reload. It's first time, because in next VC I haven't so problems..

Comment: and I see that func tableView get good new data, because when print(my.Name) I see new data from DB, but in Simulator I see old data (without reload)

Comment: It's hard to say what the issue is without seeing the app. Make sure you try running the reloadData function at the bottom of the other functions to see if it has any effect