# Action button works only once

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, button, action

I'm working on an ios app where I have a button that needs to run a lot of calculation every time you click but the button action works only the first time. Can anyone help me with this ?

This is the code of the button :

```
@IBAction func Calculate_btn(_ sender: UIButton) {

    s2 = 0.0
    mintext.text = ""
    maxtext.text = ""
    avtext.text = ""

    if speedUser.text == "" {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Give the speed to calculate the new temperature !", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    else if (Int(speedUser.text!)!<0) || (Int(speedUser.text!)!>20) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Give a valid speed : between 0 and 20 Km/h!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    else {
        refTot = ref + ref2
        rcfTot = rcf + rcf2
        airPermTot = airPermFab + airPermFab2

        print("refTot",refTot)
        print("rcfTot",rcfTot)
        print("airPermTot",airPermTot)

        var s2 = (speedUser.text! as NSString).floatValue

        Calcul(s: s2, rc: refTot, re: rcfTot, air: airPermTot)

        s2 = 0

    }
}
```

Comment: what does `Calcul` is doing? is it performing any UI task?

Comment: Calcul is doing a lot of physical calculation and put the results in a chart and 4 labels @Mukesh

Comment: Have you used breakpoints to prove that the method only runs once (very unlikely) when you touch the button? When you step through the code using the debugger is your  logic correct?

Comment: @RoboticCat yes I tried everything, and the action on the button works only the first time

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to reload the data within the button this link is similar. They call a function within their button :)
[reloadData() isn't work in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018589/reloaddata-isnt-work-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

The function doesnt run one time also it works everytime. But you always call same parameters

```
s2 = 0.0
mintext.text = ""
maxtext.text = ""
avtext.text = ""
```

Declare this parameters out of function

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's still looking for an answer to this issue, try declaring your UIAlertController (as well as accompanying actions) with an empty initializer before the viewDidLoad(). Then within the viewDidLoad(), construct it with some parameters as well as any UIAlertActions that you want to accompany it. For some reason (I'm not really sure why), when you declare an alert controller as an immutable and add its actions all within the same IBAction/class function, it doesn's seem to accomplish its goal after the first time. I had an app with this exact same issue. The alert would appear each time, but the handler function would not accomplish its task. No errors thrown either. For example, this is the structure I've come up with that works:

```
class SomeClass: UIViewController, OtherSubClasses
{
     var alertDialog: UIAlertController = UIAlertController()
     var ok: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction()
     var cancel: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction()
     // anything else needed

     override func viewDidLoad()
     {
          super.viewDidLoad()

          // define the alert dialog controller
          alertDialog = UIAlertController(title: "some title", 
               message: "some message to user", preferredStyle: .alert)

          // defines OK button for alert dialog
          ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler:
          {
              (action) -> Void in
                // compartmentalized handler in the form of a function,
                // called with the self prefix if defined within the same file
                  self.someHandlerFunc()
          })

          // defines cancel button for alert dialog
          cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

          // now add them to the controller
          alertDialog.addAction(ok)
          alertDialog.addAction(cancel)
     }

     func someHandlerFunc()
     {
          // handler function logic called in whichever action needed
     }

     @IBAction func someButtonPressed(_ sender: Any)
     {
          // here is where you want to place logic for when the button is pressed,
          // then simply present the alert dialog that is standing by

          self.present(alertDialog, animated: true, completion, nil)
     }
}
```

By doing it this way, not only does it eliminate the single use issue but you can also reuse the same alert controller and change it as needed in any other action functions. For example, changing the message is as simple as:

```
alertDialog.message = "some new message to the user"
```

In terms of the OP's code, I would simply move the declarations/definitions as described, and move the actual calculation logic into its own function called by the handler within the alert action object. The condition checks can still exist within the action method, of course. However, I'm sure he's come across his own solution at this point.